# Action Sheet - Colors

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I tried adding an action sheet to my viewport, it did work but it is totally black.

I want to put the background of the actionsheet to white. What are the mixins or class used for it that would only modify the actionsheet's background. I can't seem to find the good combination or the proper mixins :S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$sheet-bg-color : COLOR;
$sheet-bg-gradient: GRADIENT;
```

- Start `compass watch` in resource/sass directory (Terminal)
- Put those lines of scss in APP.SCSS before the imports.